# Using Regex to catch text until first occurrence of new line

Tags: python, regex

Consider I have the following text:

```
== Sejarah == \n Berkas:Gunung Kawi Rice Terrace Tampaksiring 1.jpg|kiri|jmpl|200px|Sawah di sekitar Candi Tebing Gunung Kawi, Tampaksiring, Bali. \n  \n  \n \n Jepang menduduki Bali selama Perang Dunia II dan saat itu seorang perwira militer bernama I Gusti Ngurah Rai membentuk pasukan Bali 'pejuang kemerdekaan'. Berkas:Bali Labeled.png|jmpl|225px|Peta topografi Pulau Bali \n \n === Daftar kabupaten dan kota di Bali ==
```

And I want to replace all the data from Berkas: and until first occurrence of \n which means:

```
Berkas:Gunung Kawi Rice Terrace Tampaksiring 1.jpg|kiri|jmpl|200px|Sawah di sekitar Candi Tebing Gunung Kawi, Tampaksiring, Bali. \n
Berkas:Bali Labeled.png|jmpl|225px|Peta topografi Pulau Bali \n
```

I tried using regex `df['Body'] = df['Body'].str.replace('Berkas:[\s\S]*?\n','',regex=True)` without success
How do I tell the regex that \n should be the first found?  What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Is the  text you show at the top a *literal string* or a *string literal*? If it is a string literal, all you need is `r'Berkas:.*'` - and it is a *string literal* that can be pasted into your *code*, not regex101.com, and run against your *actual data*.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex worked for me partially.  Only issue is that it also returns an extra `\`

```
Berkas:[\s\S]*?[\\\n]
```

Output:

> Berkas:Gunung Kawi Rice Terrace Tampaksiring
>   1.jpg|kiri|jmpl|200px|Sawah di sekitar Candi Tebing Gunung Kawi, Tampaksiring, Bali. \
>
> Berkas:Bali Labeled.png|jmpl|225px|Peta topografi Pulau Bali \

Output for this is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text =  "== Sejarah == \n Berkas:Gunung Kawi Rice Terrace Tampaksiring 1.jpg|kiri|jmpl|200px|Sawah di sekitar Candi Tebing Gunung Kawi, Tampaksiring, Bali. \n  \n  \n \n Jepang menduduki Bali selama Perang Dunia II dan saat itu seorang perwira militer bernama I Gusti Ngurah Rai membentuk pasukan Bali 'pejuang kemerdekaan'. Berkas:Bali Labeled.png|jmpl|225px|Peta topografi Pulau Bali \n \n === Daftar kabupaten dan kota di Bali == "
pattern = "Berkas.*\n" 
## list of data from Berkas
Berkas_list = re.findall(pattern, text)
for data in Berkas_list:
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
Berkas:Gunung Kawi Rice Terrace Tampaksiring 1.jpg|kiri|jmpl|200px|Sawah di sekitar Candi Tebing Gunung Kawi, Tampaksiring, Bali. 

Berkas:Bali Labeled.png|jmpl|225px|Peta topografi Pulau Bali
```

Comment: I have tried em `https://regex101.com/r/OJCI1f/1` but still not work

Comment: Problem is in the text string on Online Regex tester. 
"\n" is not considered as new line in text string. 
[https://regex101.com/r/OJCI1f/2]
You can try locally, It will work.